# How can I loop thru two columns of grouped values in Excel VBA and create a helper column that identifies the differences/similarities per each group?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through a list of Group IDs in column A and Division IDs in column B and return the values as shown in column C (please see below picture).

If the Division value in column B is different (not all the same) for that given Group ID in column A, return a value called: "MIXED" for the entire group in column C, where it's the same, return a value of "SAME" etc. (please see below picture).

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, objDic2 As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String
    Dim arrData
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set objDic2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rngData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    ' Load data into an array
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ' Loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1)
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            If Not objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, 2) Then
                objDic2(sKey) = "Mixed"
            Else
                If objDic2(sKey) = "Unique" Then
                    objDic2(sKey) = "Same"
                End If
            End If
        Else
            objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, 2)
            objDic2(sKey) = "Unique"
        End If
    Next i
    ' Update the 3rd col
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        arrData(i, 3) = objDic2(arrData(i, 1))
    Next i
    ' Write output to sheet
    rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your helpful VBA response. This solution worked like a charm as well! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA for this, you could use a formula (this is for Row 2):

=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$6,A2)=1,"UNIQUE",IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$6,A2,$B$2:$B$6,"<>"&B2)>0,"MIXED","SAME"))

(adjust the formula for your no of rows), or, if you have your data in an EXCEL table:

=IF(COUNTIFS([GROUP ID],[@[GROUP ID]])=1,"UNIQUE",IF(COUNTIFS([GROUP ID],[@[GROUP ID]],[DIVISION],"<>"&[@DIVISION])>0,"MIXED","SAME"))

Comment: Thank you for your helpful and quick response. The formula solutions worked like a charm! Thank you!